# Animated countdown timer on Windows Outlook

Tags: php, email, timer, outlook

There is any way to build animate countdown timer to send in E-mail campaign? I build this with PHP:

`<img src="http://example.com/timer.php?end=2017-01" alt="timer" />`

and result:

[image: example]

It working correct on every E-mail client ( Thunderbird, browser, Android, Outlook Mac OS), but didn`t work on Windows Outlook ( 2016, 2013 etc ) - displays first frame of animated GIF only. There is any way to build this timer to work on WIndows Outlook?

Comment: What do you mean by "no on Windows Outlook ( 2016, 2013 etc )". Could you provide us more explanation or a screenshot. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexandreT - On Windows Outlook ( 2013, 2016 ) displays first frame of animated GIF only. On Outlook Mac OS it working correctly.

Comment: It seems to be a bug in Windows Outlook 2013: http://techin.oureverydaylife.com/include-animated-gif-outlook-email-21585.html